# HSQLDB run from code connect from another client

Tags: java, hsqldb

I need to create Server of HSQLDB from my code, run it and connect from another application (for e.x. by runManagerSwing.bat)

Here are my code:

```
HsqlProperties p = new HsqlProperties();
        p.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:./db/idt_simulatordb");
        p.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "idt_simulatordb");
        p.setProperty("server.port", "9001");
        Server server2 = new Server();
        server2.setProperties(p);
server2.start();
    // I even can connect to my server from the same application
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001   /idt_simulatordb", "sa", "");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();    // statements
            String expression1 = "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS simulators CASCADE;\n";
            String expression2 = "CREATE SCHEMA SIMULATORS AUTHORIZATION SA;";
            String expression3 = "CREATE TABLE SIMULATORS.dirtyhack();";
            st.executeUpdate(expression1);    // run the query
            st.executeUpdate(expression2);    // run the query
            st.executeUpdate(expression3);    // run the query
//
            st.close();
            conn.close();



server2.shutdownWithCatalogs(Database.CLOSEMODE_NORMAL);
```

But when I put the breakpoint after server run and try to connect to my server from runManagerSwing I got timeout error.

But if I launch server from bat-file, then everything is ok.

I suppose that I have to use `MainInvoker` but I don't know how to pass argument and how to shutdown server after all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the server after the last line you reported

```
...
server2.setProperties(p);
server2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal because when you re hitting the breakpoint you are suspending the db as well so you cant connect to it.

Solution:
Make your breakpoint suspend the thread it is in only and not the whole program. If you on intellij right click the breakpoint and put the suspend option to "Thread" not to "all"